# Parsing dates and times from string in many combinations

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I need to parse dates and times from strings. The Problem is that the strings can have any possible format. But I also get the format strings.

So i get:

```
Date = "9/15/2010"
Time = "16:12:45"
DateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy"
TimeFormat = "h:mm:ss"
TimeZone = "+2:00:00"  // +/- and time in TimeFormat
```

But i have some problems parsing these strings.

I can't parse the time

```
DateTime.ParseExact("16:12:45","h:mm:ss",null,DateTimeStyles.None);
```

does not work and causes a FormatException. What is wrong with this call?

If the DateFormat contains slashes, i need to escape them `@"M\/dd\/yyyy"`. Are there any other chars that would need escaping?

Can i parse the whole DateTime in one? Somehting like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Date+' '+Time+' '+TimeZone,DateFormat+' '+TimeFormat+' +'+TimeFormat,null,DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: you need to use `hh` instead of just `h`.

Comment: Without culture infomration this is impossible, as you'll never know whether

`9/12/2010` represents september, 12th or december, 9th.

Comment: It is possible, because i use the format. Parsing a x/x/xxxx date is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with this call?

The *"h:mm:ss"* format string expects the hours element to be in 12-hour format (`h`); The hours in your string are in 24-hour format so you need to use `H` instead:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("16:12:45", "H:mm:ss", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

> Are there any other chars that would need escaping?

Any literal character in your string that clashes with [a format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) will need to be escaped. For example, `/` is the date separator but `\/` means the literal `/` character; `:` is the time separator but `\:` means the literal `:` character; `y` is one of the year specifiers but `\y` is the literal `y` character.

> Can i parse the whole DateTime in one?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks, the strings are coming from a delphi program where h can also be 24 hour format.

Comment: How does this work when the format changes? You have to know the format in advance but your question states that the format can change.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var @return = (DateTime?)null;
if (source != null)
{
    source = source.Trim();
    if (source.Length > 0)
    {
        var fs = new string[]
        {
            "d MMMM yyyy h:mm tt",
            "d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
            "d MMMM yyyy HH:mm",
            "d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "d MMMM yyyy",
            "d/M/yy h:mm tt",
            "d/M/yy h:mm:ss tt",
            "d/M/yy HH:mm",
            "d/M/yy HH:mm:ss",
            "d/M/yy",
            "d/M/yyyy HH:mm",
            "d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
            "d/M/yyyy",
            "d/M/yyyy h:mm tt",
            "d-MMMM-yy HH:mm",
            "d-MMMM-yyyy h:mm tt",
            "d-MMMM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
            "d-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm",
            "d-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "d-MMMM-yyyy",
            "d-MMM-yy",
            "d-MMM-yy h:mm tt",
            "d-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt",
            "d-MMM-yy HH:mm",
            "d-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss",
            "d-MMM-yyyy",
            "d-M-yy h:mm tt",
            "d-M-yy h:mm:ss tt",
            "d-M-yy HH:mm",
            "d-M-yy HH:mm:ss",
            "d-M-yy",
            "d-M-yyyy",
            "yyyy/M/d h:mm tt",
            "yyyy/M/d h:mm:ss tt",
            "yyyy/M/d HH:mm",
            "yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy/M/d",
            "yyyy-M-d h:mm tt",
            "yyyy-M-d h:mm:ss tt",
            "yyyy-M-d HH:mm",
            "yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy-M-d",
            "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
        };
        @return = DateTime.ParseExact(source, fs,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
    }
}
return @return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which culture the original string belongs to? If you do you can specify a culture specific DateTimeStyle when calling Parse()

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("<your specific date>", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("<your culture>").DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: No. I don't know the culture. I only get the informations i have written in the top post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom DateTimeFormatInfo and pass that into DateTime.Parse. Like this:

```
string dateValue = string.Format("{0} {1}", "9/15/2010", "16:12:45");
var customDateTimeFormatInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
customDateTimeFormatInfo.FullDateTimePattern = string.Format("{0} {1}", "M/dd/yyyy", "h:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateValue, customDateTimeFormatInfo);
```

No escaping required and handled your "h:mm:ss" fine with no modification required.